# Adding new class library to the existing BitBucket repository

Tags: git, visual-studio, bitbucket

I have a visual studio solution hosted in BitBucket, and no problem with syncing code. I added a new class library in the solution recently which is referenced by other previous libraries.

The problem is that I can't find any option to add this new class library to the existing repository in BitBucket. As a result, I can't push it up and causes building problem for other users.

I used to use traditional TFS in which you just needed to right click on the project and select add to source control, but this is not the case now.

Comment: Did you add it through a nuget package or do you have a local copy of the assembly that you added a reference to? If the latter, you would need to decide where, inside the repository, such assemblies should live so that you can put it there and make a reference to it from there, and then also make sure you commit that assembly to the repository.

Comment: If you added it as a project, you just need to commit the class library to the repository. You should be able to do that inside Visual Studio.

Comment: Thanks Lasse, yes it's local. I see your point but I can't find options for the procedure you described. Could you please guide me for these steps: "_you can put it there_" , "_make a reference to it from there_".

Comment: There is no track of the new library in the commit window

Comment: Are you using the git extension to Visual Studio? Is it listed under excluded files?

Comment: Yes, I have. No, the new library is not listed in changes window excluded or untracked.

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio? You need at least 2012+Tools for Git extension or 2013 to manage Git repos from within VS; older versions must use command line Git to add/commit

Comment: @GiulioVian I'm using VS2013